# Html css боковые линии блоков вида "]" слева-справа

Tags: html, css3, html5, scss

Нужно сделать боковые линии у блоков. Не знаю как сделать и в какую строну двигаться.
Прошу совета или решения.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-bottom: -.5em;
}

h1:before, h1:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

h1:before {
  margin-right: .25em;
} 

h1:after {
  margin-left: .25em;
}

section:first-child h1:before, section:last-child h1:after {
  border-color: transparent;
}

section {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

section:nth-child(odd), section:last-child {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

section:nth-child(even), section:last-child {
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

div {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>01</h1>
    <div>Нужно сделать боковые линии у блоков. Не знаю как сделать и в какую строну двигаться. Прошу совета или решения.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>02</h1>
    <div>Нужно сделать боковые линии у блоков. Не знаю как сделать и в какую строну двигаться. Прошу совета или решения.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>03</h1>
    <div>Нужно сделать боковые линии у блоков. Не знаю как сделать и в какую строну двигаться. Прошу совета или решения.</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитай про ::after и ::before, должно помочь

```
content: '';
width = 15%;
height = 2px;
```

И далее, думаю поймёшь в какую сторону двигаться

Comment: если бы просто боковая граница, нет проблем, а мне именно повторить картинку нужно, граница скобкой идет. думаю через fieldset попробовать

Answer (score -1):

Просто делаешь два класса, у одного все границы кроме правой, у второго кроме левой:

```css
.no-right-border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.no-left-border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-right-border">
  <p style="margin-top: 20px">Текст</p>
</div>
<div class="no-left-border">
  <p style="margin-top: 20px">Текст</p>
</div>
```